# Basic minimum, maximum, average, and total of inputted numbers not working

Tags: java, input, numbers

I can not get this program to run correctly. All my answers, Min, Max, Average are zero. I know I initialized them to zero at the beginning, but they should change through out the code?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
int a,b;
int max;
double average;
int min;
int total;
max=0;
min=0;
total=0;
Scanner keyboardInput = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println(" Enter a number :");
a = keyboardInput.nextInt();
System.out.println(" You entered :"+ a);
if (a>=0)
{a=max;
max=min;}
total=a;
System.out.println(" Max and min are "+ max  +" & " + min + " The total and average is    :" +total + " & "+a);             
System.out.println(" Enter a second number");

b = keyboardInput.nextInt();

System.out.println(" You entered :"+ b);
if (b>=a)
{b=max;}
if  (b<=a)
{b=min;}

average= (a+b)/2;
total= a+b;
System.out.println(" Max and min are "+ max + " & " + min + " and the total & average     are :" +total + " & " +average +" respectively.");

//c = keyboardInput.nextDouble();


}
```

}

output: 
 Enter a number :

2

You entered :2

Max and min are 0 & 0 The total and average is :0 & 0

Enter a second number

3

You entered :3

Max and min are 0 & 0 and the total & average are :0 & 0.0 respectively.

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking here. Also tag java for this

Comment: I am asking for the first set of code, why do I keep getting zeros for everything in my output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have the assignment reversed:

This line:

```
a=max;
```

Should be:

```
max=a;
```

`max` is zero and you are overwriting `a` with `max`, making `a` zero too.

You have made the same mistake with `b` too.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
 if (a>=0)
 {  max=a;
    max=min;  }
```

The max should be assigned to a and min should be assigned to max `max=a` and `min=max`. Otherwise it is setting `a` to `max` which is `0` and then `max` to `min` which is again `0`.

```
if (a>=0)
 {  max=a;
    min=max;  }
```

Update the assignment issue everywhere. Remember left variable is assigned the value of right variable

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a, b;
    int max;
    double average;
    int min;
    int total;
    max = 0;
    min = 0;
    total = 0;
    Scanner keyboardInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println(" Enter a number :");
    a = keyboardInput.nextInt();
    System.out.println(" You entered :" + a);
    if (a >= 0) {
        //modify a=max;
        max = a;
        //modify max=min;
        min = max;
    }
    total = a;
    System.out.println(" Max and min are " + max + " & " + min
            + " The total and average is    :" + total + " & " + a);
    System.out.println(" Enter a second number");

    b = keyboardInput.nextInt();

    System.out.println(" You entered :" + b);
    if (b >= a) {
        //modify b=max;
        max = b ;
    }
    if (b <= a) {
        b = min;
    }
    // modify average= (a+b)/2;
    average = (double)(a + b) / 2;
    total = a + b;
    System.out.println(" Max and min are " + max + " & " + min
            + " and the total & average     are :" + total + " & "
            + average + " respectively.");

    // c = keyboardInput.nextDouble();

}
```